# Why input text disable are "compact" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, oracle-adf

Why input text in Internet Explorer appear "compact"?

In Mozilla and Chrome are comportament normal but in IE is different.

The code in CSS is this:

```
<af:inputText id="it9" simple="true" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.it9}"
                                      disabled="true" partialTriggers="it6"
                                      valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.enableCategory}"
                                      autoSubmit="true" contentStyle="width:99%">
                            <af:autoSuggestBehavior suggestedItems="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.getFamily}"/>
                        </af:inputText>
```

I don't know what I have to do. I tried to use a different font size but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with browsers. We cannot expect all the browsers to function alike always.
You can see https://java.net/jira/browse/ADFEMG-23 for workaround for this.